# How do I configure a Ricoh MP C2050 (multifunction) fax to work

Tags: fax

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and have a Ricoh C2050 connected via network.

Printing works fine but I'm not able to configure it that fax works. I cannot find anything that looks as a fax setting.

Is my driver wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.